# why does a local PrintWriter interfere with another local PrintWriter?

Tags: java, console, printwriter

In this program, the third string never gets printed.  Why?

(This Java program was run on Eclipse Indigo on Ubuntu 10.10.)

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Tester
{
    static void nested()
    {
        PrintWriter object2 = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
        object2.println("second");
        object2.close(); // delete this line to make all strings print
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrintWriter object1 = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
        object1.println("first");
        Tester.nested();
        object1.println("third");
        object1.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By closing the nested `PrintWriter`, you also close the embedded `System.out` stream, which seemingly prevents further writes to it (although I would expect an exception really instead of swallowing output).

So the entire problem can be reduced to:

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println("first");
        System.out.close();
        System.out.println("second");        
    }
}
```

This too doesn't print anymore after *"first"*, but also doesn't throw an exception. A very quick debugging session shows there's a call to a Sun native function, which is a little harder to debug into.

**Update***

This is the culprit: `System.out` is of type `java.io.PrintStream` and it contains the following *lovely* method:

```
private void write(String s) {
    try {
        synchronized (this) {
            ensureOpen();
            textOut.write(s);
            textOut.flushBuffer();
            charOut.flushBuffer();
            if (autoFlush && (s.indexOf('\n') >= 0))
                out.flush();
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    catch (IOException x) {
        trouble = true;
    }
}
```

The `ensureOpen()` method indeed throws an exception, but it's swallowed here and the `trouble` flag is set (a well known anti-pattern). This thus silently ignores further writes to the closed stream.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [close()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#close%28%29) it says

> Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with
>   it. Closing a previously closed stream has no effect

So my guess is that it is releasing the System.out and hence can't be used again. Also, I added a `System.out.println("Finished");` line at the end and it doesn't output anything if a close has been called on `System.out` in the code. Try it out.